# string length is not showing properly

Tags: c

So i have 3 codes here,

1. in first one i haven't initialized the string !
   and strlen shows "3" in ans
2. in 2nd one i initialized it with 3 char and still the same ans "3"
3. in 3rd i initialized it with 4 char and output is "4"

Sorry guys, if it was too obvious but i am new and so confused why it shows "3" in output in first code.

```
//1st
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char y[20];
    printf("%d",strlen(y));
    return 0;
}

//2nd
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char y[20]="yas";
    printf("%d",strlen(y));
    return 0;
}
//3rd
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char y[20]="asds";
    printf("%d",strlen(y));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing in 1) case is undefined behavior.
Because the `y` is uninitialized.

Also [`strlen`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strlen.3.html) returns `size_t` , the correct format to print its return value is :

`printf("strlen(y) = (%zu)\n",strlen(y));`

Comment: thanks that helps so does `sizeof()` function also returns `size_t` ?

Comment: `sizeof` is **not** a function, it is an operator. You see a lot of `sizeof (type)` when `type` is just a data type, and this is the required form. If you want the size of an object, you simply use `sizeof object`. Anyway, the result is of type `size_t`, right. (It helps if you read the standard.)

Answer (score 0):

the function of strlen will stop when meet '\0'.

in your first code , char y[20] was not initialized. the values in the array could be anything left in the stack. it happened to be that y[3]=='\0'.

so the strlen(y) could be any value in other environment

Comment: maybe you are right but i tried it on online compilers and they all gives the same ans but when i change "20" to "100" it gave "4" as output and when i changed it to "10" answer was "0" is this pattern? i am new so sorry if i am giving you hard time with silly questions !